# Nuxt.js router.push doesn't fully redirect to another page while using asyncData query

Tags: laravel, cors, nuxt.js

I am using asyncData query in one of my pages:

```
async asyncData({$axios, query}) {
  const id = query.id;

  try {
    const {data} = await $axios.$get(`http://localhost:8000/api/question/${id}`);
    return {
      question: data

    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
},
```

Whenever I try to access another route from this page, for example:

```
@click="$router.push('/solution'); addTodo(question.keywords); addTodo(option.keywords)">
```

It redirects me to this page /solution, but the request to access API still goes from previous page (question/id)

Accessing localhost:3000/solution page:
[image]

CORS works in every other page, so I think the issue is here with redirections.

What would be possible solutions to fix this?

Also, this is what I see in Network tab:

I think referer should be: localhost:3000/solution

[image]

Comment: Here's the link to Firefox console error: https://imgur.com/e6UXP5z @sideshowbarker

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8000/api/getsolution. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

As I can see it's CORS errors, but as far as I know everything is alright with the CORS, I have checked the back-end a few times. Also, everything works perfectly on other pages

Comment: the front-end path is localhost:3000/solution, while back-end calls localhost:8000/api/getsolution. I am calling localhost:8000/api/getsolution in the asyncData method (in solution route)

Comment: My back-end is Laravel and I am using https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors, everything is enabled [*]. By saying update the question to show CORS config - could you clarify a bit more what you mean?

Comment: Oh, of course. config/cors.php -> 'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

Comment: Oh, this one is empty 'paths' => []. Adding http://localhost:3000 didn't help. Should I add something else?

Comment: I dunno but maybe try setting it to `'paths' => ['api/*']` I guess

Comment: That actually helped with the CORS errors, setting it to 'paths' => ['api/*']. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Adding `'paths' => ['api/*']` to Laravel back-end CORS config helped.